# ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation xxx violates not-null constraint - Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a question regarding the @GeneratedValue annotation from Spring JPA.

This is my class:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private Integer quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;



    public Product(String name, Double price, Integer quantity, Category category, Manufacturer manufacturer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.category = category;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
}
```

And when I try to add a new product I get this error:

```
2021-12-06 18:03:02.013 ERROR 3720 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "product" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Dress, 333, 33, 1, 1).
2021-12-06 18:03:02.028 ERROR 3720 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [id" of relation "product]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "product" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Dress, 333, 33, 1, 1).
```

Here is the save method from my service class:

```
@Override
    public Optional<Product> save(String name, Double price, Integer quantity, Long categoryId, Long manufacturerId) {
        Category category = this.categoryRepository.findById(categoryId).orElseThrow(() -> new CategoryNotFoundException(categoryId));
        Manufacturer manufacturer = this.manufacturerRepository.findById(manufacturerId).orElseThrow(() -> new ManufacturerNotFoundException(manufacturerId));

        this.productRepository.deleteByName(name);

        return Optional.of(this.productRepository.save(new Product(name, price, quantity, category, manufacturer)));
    }
```

Honestly I don't realize how this happens. I read somewhere that `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is not supported by PostgreSQL, but I don't think that's it because I used the same generation type for the `Category` and `Manufacturer` tables and I can add new tuples to them no problem. I tried using generation type SEQUENCE and **it works**, but I don't want to use that generation type and I don't understand why IDENTITY **won't work here** when it worked on the other who tables. Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** Tested it with `GenerationType.AUTO` and it works, but still shows the same error for type IDENTITY.

**Edit 2:** Sharing the SQL for creating the Product table and Category table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.product
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    price double precision,
    quantity integer,
    category_id bigint,
    manufacturer_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk1mtsbur82frn64de7balymq9s FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
        REFERENCES public.category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkq5vxx1bolpwm1sngn6krtwsjn FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id)
        REFERENCES public.manufacturers (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.product
    OWNER to wp;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.category
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('category_id_seq'::regclass),
    description character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT category_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.category
    OWNER to wp;
```

**Final edit:** My question has been answered, for some reason my primary key was not set to auto increment and that was causing the problems. I believe it was because I created the table with just the `@Id` annotation and after it was created I added the generation strategy (which did not set the `id` to auto increment.

Comment: Using **Project Lombok** annotations in JPA `@Entity` might cause errors. Before running your code, please check the bytecode in the **target** folder. I got an error using `@Data` annotation on a JPA entity in IntelliJ IDEA Are you sure you need `@NoArgsConstructor`?

Comment: How do you try to add a product, with code or an API request/call? Can you add the code? Btw, I use Postgres with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` and it works very well.

Comment: @BinyaminRegev I know that the ```@Data``` annotation from Lombok can cause problems, that's why I use the ```@Getter``` and ```@Setter``` annotations (they don't cause the problem, also I use them on the other 2 classes and they work fine no problem). Also I need the ```@NoArgsConstructor``` because Hibernate needs that type of constructor in order to create the entity. - I add the code with a request, I will add the code to my original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For it to work, you have to change somethings in your Product table.

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) just work if your ID column is SERIAL type.

Check if the ID column is that type. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    etc...
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to Spring Data JPA, where can I see that SQL that you posted?

Comment: Relax no problem, you need to check the DDL of your Product table, into the PostgreSQL DB

Comment: Okay now I see it and it doesn't have the ```SERIAL``` tag or the auto increment logic. I also compared it to the other tables and it's definitely constructed different. I edited my original post. Do you know how this could have happened? And why is it when I change the annotation, the changes are not implemented for the SQL?

Comment: Great! You just need to copy the logic from the other tables (it's just modify the type of id column to serial).

Comment: better use `bigserial` if they want the 64-bit version as shown

Answer (score 0):

I would like to summerize what need to be covered in order to solve the issue:

1. Create a table with a `Serial` type

```
    CREATE TABLE post (
      id  SERIAL NOT NULL,
      title VARCHAR(255),
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
```

2. Define in the Entity model identifier properly

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
```

3. During the records insertion, it does not matter whether via SQL script or Hibernate, DO NOT set ID filed.
   For example:

```
   INSERT INTO post (title)
   VALUES ('High-Performance Java Persistence')
```